# Java osx spotify top bar on both osx and windows?

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to make the top bar look like on the image below in Java? If so, how? :)

[image]

Comment: Anything is possible. :)

Comment: :) But how? :) Would be super awesome to get that same feeling on the top bar. Imo the top bar i what makes java apps look like iframed webpages

Answer (score 0):

Here's a program that kinda does what you requested:

```
public class Spot {
    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {
        JWindow f = new JWindow();
        f.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new URL(
                "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPgpQ.png")))));
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If that's not what you wanted, then you should clarify the question.